# Impossible to see Sharepoint Hosted a App in a frame

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint Hosted App that works outside of a SharePoint Page.

If I insert as web part or app part in a page I get an error message.
It says that's impossible to see these contents in a frame 
and that for security reasons cannot be seen.

Is there something I could do to make it visible?

With other apps I have no problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved adding this in my Client Web Part page:

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming1" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally to stop the framing attacks the site has iframe disabled. The iframe can be disabled at page level or IIS level.

Page Level : Check if the page has meta tag saying **DENY** eg meta name=”X-FRAME-OPTIONS” content=”DENY” />

OR

IIS setting : Follow these steps: 1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. 2. In the Connections pane on the left side, expand the Sites folder and select the site that you want to protect. 3. Double-click the HTTP Response Headers icon in the feature list in the middle. Check the iframe options ,it might have **DENY**.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72987/is-there-a-way-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-or-at-least-modify-it

Comment: I've checked that neither HTTP Response Header in IIS nor the page have the options you said. Anyway, I was looking into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921(v=office.15).aspx but haven't solved yet.