# SharePoint SSRS Report in iFrame

Tags: reporting-services, iframe

How can I display an SSRS Report in an iFrame?

Is there some setting somewhere to enable the content to be viewed?

I know bing allows their page to be viewed in an iFrame, whereas google does not.

This is what I get when I place an iFrame WebPart on my SharePoint page.

[image: iFrame Error Message]

Later, I want to be able to display this report on another site, so I want to use the iFrame feature.

Answer (score 1):

Check if X-Frame-Options is set to SAMEORIGIN on the SSRS web server? You can check it in web.config or using the IIS management console

Few links which may help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085306/disable-x-frame-options-in-mvc3-or-iis-7-5

[Is there a way to disable X-FRAME-OPTIONS response header, or at least modify it?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72987/is-there-a-way-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-or-at-least-modify-it)

Comment: REVA, your answer led me closer to the solution. I made sure that my url had the same protocol and domain, and it worked. However, I am interested in allowing a different origin to access this report in an iFrame. Do you know of any other resources directly related to that?

Comment: You can try  X-FRAME-OPTIONS ALLOW-FROM http://siteurl/, however it may not be supported in all browsers.