# Display SharePoint 2013 in a frame

Tags: sharepoint-online, iframe

I'm embedding a SharePoint Online page in a local web application. Almost all functions were working well like normal.

But since SharePoint Online was upgraded to 2013 version, we cannot use it properly.

For example, when filtering on view, SAMEORIGIN message comes:

> Refused to display
>   '_https://.../_layouts/15/filter.aspx?ListId…5FNAME&ViewId={E0B8747C-5FED-4E53-8C6E-262A44BBFFB4}&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Or access denied when access `parent.location`...

How can I setup our site for SP 2013 working in frame?

(tried adding `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"` attribute to `iframe` but not works)

Comment: Look at [my answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/95470/24905) in this thread. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Hello Thanhma,
Did you get to it's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Simply because you're trying to encapsulate a cloud-based system into an internal IIS folder structure.

You can not add Sharepoint online page in an iframe because of the same origin policy that most of the sites on internet adopted this days. This is mainly for security reasons to avoid from web attacks like Clickjacking and XSS.

If you want to display the content of the sharepoint online into different domain, than try to use provider hosted app in windows azure or develop a Napa sharepoint hosted app which can make cross domain requests in REST or ajax

Comment: Yep. This question is 4 years old and the previous version of SharePoint Online (2010) was supporting embedded in iframe. Obviously it shouldn't be, and MS did restrict it.
Anyway, this question need an answer and I think yours should be suitable for later visitors.